# Get the frequency of each datetime column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have this DataFrame with N DateTime columns, an example below is of 3 columns

```
1/26/2020   2021-6-9   2019/2/28
2/2/2020    2021-6-8   2019/3/31
2/9/2020    2021-6-7   2019/4/30
2/16/2020   2021-6-6   2019/5/31
```

I am trying to write a code that can figure out the frequency (e.g: D, 3D, W, M, Y, ...etc) of each column automatically and accurately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to convert those columns to datetime format, and then use the diff function, it gives you the intervals of days:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = { 
     'A':["1/26/2020", "2/2/2020", "2/9/2020"],
    "B": ["2021-6-9", "2021-6-8", "2021-6-7"]}

data = pd.DataFrame(df)
data["A"] = pd.to_datetime(data["A"])
data["B"] = pd.to_datetime(data["B"])
data_diff = data.diff(axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried your answer, I think some of it didn't actually work

Running your code using axis=1 gives inaccurate results for both columns, but using axis=0 works very fine for column A but not B

I tried to sort the columns ten apply some internal data converting by going through the year, month, day levels, however, they kept giving the same results

Comment: I have tried to run your code but added **data["A"] = data["A"].sort_values(ascending=True, ignore_index=True)** for each column I go through and it seems working. Thank you!!